# Count all values in a summary in comma separated list in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new to excel so go easy on me. I've got a comma separated column with the following values

Red,Green,blue

Green,Red

Blue

On another sheet I have this

Blue 1

Red 1

Green 1

Thing is the count if only counts the first value and I'd like all the values in the list to be counted in the summary if that makes sense? I've used the following code but this only counts the first value in the column

`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$K:$K,Summary!B11)`

Comment: Try this: `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$K:$K, "*" & Summary!B11 & "*")`

Comment: Try this: `=SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&Summary!B11&",",","&Sheet1!$K:$K&","))))`

Answer (score 2):

Try using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd> function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,  C1:C3,
     b,  "," & A1:A3 & ",",
     MMULT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&a&",",TOROW(b))),SEQUENCE(ROWS(b),,,0)))
```

---

The above formula will spill down automatically; therefore you don't need to use the fill down handle. However, you can use another approach as well.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&C1&",",","&$A$1:$A$3&","))))
```

---

OfCourse the above formula needs to fill down, also ensure to change the cell reference and ranges accordingly as per your suit.

---

Answer (score 0):

### Count Delimited Matches

[image]

```
=LET(sData,A2:A4,dData,C2:C6,dlm,",",er,NA(),
    ts,TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(sData&","),,dlm),
BYROW(dData,LAMBDA(r,IFERROR(ROWS(FILTER(ts,ts=r)),er))))
```